# AlarmReceiver not change data when callback

Tags: android

i have an application use `AlarmManage`, `Notification`, `BroadcastService` to notify to user after a certain period. The value as name, gender, ringtone, vibrate, ... be edited in `SharedPreferences`.

**Problem**: 
When i change value of name, gender, ... value is updated in Preference but notify not update value. However, when i restart my device, value is correct but only first run. :(

Here is source code

**AlarmReceiver.class**

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
    String name = "", ringtone = "";
    int gender, mZodiacID;
    SharedPreferences shared;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        showNotification(shared, context);
    }

    private void showNotification(SharedPreferences shared, Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, gender + " : " + name);

        gender = Integer.parseInt(shared.getString(SHARED_GENERAL_GENDER, "0"));
        name = shared.getString(SHARED_GENERAL_NAME, "");

        Log.d(TAG, gender + " : " + name);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setContentText("Xin chào " + name)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Create explicit intent for an Activity
        Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(context, AppDetailActivity.class);
        notifyIntent.putExtra(PARAM_NAME, name);
        notifyIntent.putExtra(PARAM_GENDER_ID, gender);


        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(AppDetailActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notifyIntent);

        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


        // Set ringtone for notification
        Uri alarmSound;
        ringtone = shared.getString(SHARED_NOTI_RINGTONE, "false");
        if (ringtone.equals("false")) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Default ringtone: " + ringtone);
            alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Custom ringtone: " + ringtone);
            alarmSound = Uri.parse(ringtone);
        }
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);

        // Set vibrate
        if (shared.getBoolean(SHARED_NOTI_VIBRATE, false)) {
            mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100, 200, 300});
            Log.d(TAG, "Vibrate: YES");
        } else {
            mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[]{0, 0, 0, 0});
            Log.d(TAG, "Vibrate: NO");
        }

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

**AlarmService.java**

```
public class AlarmService {
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private Context mContext;

    public AlarmService(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class), 0);
    }


    public void cancel() {
        if (mContext != null) {
            Object localObject = new Intent(mContext, AlarmReceiver.class);
            localObject = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.mContext, 0, (Intent)localObject, 0);
            ((AlarmManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)).cancel((PendingIntent)localObject);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Đã tắt thông báo hàng ngày", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
//            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Alarm can't cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        SharedPreferences shared = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        shared.edit().putBoolean(SHARED_NOTI_DAILY, true).commit();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Đã bật thông báo hàng ngày", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 1;

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

        int hous = shared.getInt(SHARED_NOTI_HOURSE, 7);
        int minute = shared.getInt(SHARED_NOTI_MINUTES, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hous);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
//        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
//                interval, pendingIntent);
        manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), interval,pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Phương thức start được gọi ở đâu vây?

Comment: When you changed to value do you cancel and then create the alarm again  ?

Comment: @Nin_in_the_winD I have a SwitchPreference to turn on/ off alarm, and `start()`  called in OnPreferenceChangeListener (SettingActivity)

Comment: @RanHassid: Yes, i do. But nothing changes

Comment: Hi , can you please check in your manifest.xml file that you have the following permissions: 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
and that your broadcast receiver is registered ...

Comment: I had added 2 permission, problem: value not updated. (Broadcast receiver is registered, notify turn on)

Answer (score 0):

You could add a listener and update your notification like that.

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        // your stuff here 
    } 
};
```